# Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, global-actions

I was trying to create a new Action button for salesforce1, then I noticed something new, Lightning Action Types. "Wow" . Looks like it is not functional yet. just wondering if this is expected behavior or bug. Did anyone face this issue? i have so many lightning components. I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lightning component you wanted to show in quick action should implement `force:lightningQuickAction` or `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` interface.

> Add the force:lightningQuickAction or
>   force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader interface to a Lightning
>   component to enable it to be used as a custom action in Lightning
>   Experience or Salesforce1. You can use components that implement one
>   of these interfaces as object-specific actions in both Lightning
>   Experience and Salesforce1. You can use them as global actions only in
>   Salesforce1.

Here's the link to [section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm) where configuring the component for action is discussed.